# What's the function of aes(x,y) in geom_text(data = labels, aes(x, y, label = country), size = 5)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

In one example of my EdX course, I am wondering why we can't just put the `label` in `ggplot(mapping = aes(...))` but give the `aes(x, y)` in `geom_text`. What's the function of that? Does it specify the space to put the label when it just say `aes(x, y, label = country)`?

## life expectancy time series - lines colored by country and labeled, no legend

```
labels <- data.frame(country = countries, x = c(1975, 1965), y = c(60, 72))
gapminder %>% filter(country %in% countries) %>%
ggplot(aes(year, life_expectancy, col = country)) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_text(data = labels, aes(x, y, label = country), size = 5) +
   theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you could place `label` in the original `aes(...)` argument.

`aes` is an argument for the aesthetics of the plot, including anything such as `y`, `x`, general `size` etc. and it propagates to any further `ggplot`, `geom_...` and `stat_...` call. As such if you add `label` in the `aes` argument, it will be used as value in any function call to that specific plot, **unless** you set `inherit.aes = FALSE` at which point it will require a newly specified `aes(...)` argument.

As such the two examples below, where i use the `mtcars` dataset are equivalent.

```
data(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)

#Example 1:
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + 
    geom_smooth() + 
    geom_text(aes(label = cyl), size = 5)

#Example 2:
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, label = cyl)) + 
    geom_smooth() + 
    geom_text(size = 5)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying the aes label part! I was wondering whether I could ask another quick question. Another part that confuses me is: in aes(x, y, label = country)  does the x,y in the line refer to x = c(1975, 1965), y = c(60, 72)? And are therefore kind of used to "pin" the labels?

Comment: No problem. One beauty of `ggplot` is that the argument functionality stays the same. Thus, `x` and `y` have the same functionality as if you used `geom_point(...)` instead of `geom_text(...)`. It is the position of the point, or in this case label, and is the center of the point / label.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much, Oliver!

Comment: Again, my pleasure. I suggest marking the answer as 'answering the question' (below the upvote) to help others with similar problems locate the answer in the future. :-)